# how to compile my react file written in es6 using babel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

could you please tell me how to compile my react file written in es6 using babel ?

I tried like this
**my file**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';


class Abc extends React.Components{

    render(){
        return (
            <div>dddd</div>
        )
    }
}

render(<Abc />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**package.json**

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ifscproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel reacfiles/app.js  --presets react  --out-file build/app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
  }
}
```

when I tried **npm run build**

it generate a new file

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class Abc extends React.Components {

    render() {
        return React.createElement(
            'div',
            null,
            'dddd'
        );
    }
}

render(React.createElement(Abc, null), document.getElementById('root'));
```

it is converted react code, not es6 code why?
could you please tel me how to convert es6 code also

Updates

when I used solution it gives update code

```
'use strict';

var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

var _react = require('react');

var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);

var _reactDom = require('react-dom');

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) { if (!self) { throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called"); } return call && (typeof call === "object" || typeof call === "function") ? call : self; }

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass; }

var Abc = function (_React$Components) {
    _inherits(Abc, _React$Components);

    function Abc() {
        _classCallCheck(this, Abc);

        return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (Abc.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(Abc)).apply(this, arguments));
    }

    _createClass(Abc, [{
        key: 'render',
        value: function render() {
            return _react2.default.createElement(
                'div',
                null,
                'dddd'
            );
        }
    }]);

    return Abc;
}(_react2.default.Components);

(0, _reactDom.render)(_react2.default.createElement(Abc, null), document.getElementById('root'));
```

But when I run on server it gives me error

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
var App = require('./build/app');

var React = require('react');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
// const indexPath = path.join(__dirname, 'index.html');
const publicPath = express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public'));
app.use(publicPath);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


app.get('/get', function (req, res) {
    res.send(App);
})
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Listening to port 3000');
})
```

Comment: Since announce of ReactJS v0.13.0 Beta 1 it's possible to use capabilities of ECMAScript 6 for your React components. I dont get exactly why you are having problems with ES6.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the es2015 preset. Do the following:

- Install es2015 preset with

  ```
  npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015
  ```
- Edit your build script to:

  ```
  "build": "babel reacfiles/app.js --out-file build/app.js"
  ```
- Create a .babelrc file (and define your presets there):

.babelrc

```
{ "presets": ["es2015", "react"] }
```

Comment: i am able to generate the file , but it not loaded in sever ..:(

Comment: class ABC extends React.Component (not Components)